# What is this error "bash: line 7: 4913 Killed" emitted by the clang compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not familiar with clang. What's wrong with this snippet?

```
#include <limits>

const int y = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

int a[y];

int main() {
}
```

See the error message [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c376c9f29e886a7c).

Comment: Note that the error is not from the `clang` compiler; it comes from attempting to run the `a.out` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your program, `a.out`, was killed, probably because you tried to allocate too much memory in your array.  If your machine is a 32-bit machine, you tried to allocate 8 GiB of memory but a 32-bit compilation can only access 4 GiB in total (code and data).  If your machine is a 64-bit machine (and your compilation is a 64-bit compilation), it was still probably trying to allocate 8 GiB and it probably would have succeeded.

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, when I wrote code to use the array, the program failed to compile with errors like: `/tmp/ccupZA0o.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':` and
``/home/jleffler/gcc/v4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:74:(.text.startup+0xa5): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'`` and (almost a repeat)
``/home/jleffler/gcc/v4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:74:(.text.startup+0xb4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'`` and
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: And, FYI,  I took the code verbatim from the question and placed it into maxmem.cpp. I then compiled it on a 64-bit machine with GCC 4.8.2 and the command line: `g++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic maxmem.cpp -o maxmem`. The compilation was successful; the program ran (very fast because the array was optimized away). The `-pedantic` prevents the GCC support for VLAs, not that it was necessary since the array is not a VLA but just a rather large plain array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the information, I tried it and yes it compiled. The thing I was missing was the `-std=c++11`. Without, it complains that the limits are not a constant value even if stored inside a constant integer.